# Script that makes directories from A to Z and files in them from 1 to 9

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

Do you have any idea how would a script in shell would look like with the following conditions: When executed, it has to make Folderz from A to Z In every folder, it has to make blank file from 0-9

And on top of all, another directory has to be made with a file in it counting how many files are in each directory?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like homework. What did you try?

Comment: [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) will be useful here.

Comment: Well, this is what I found on the internet and gave it a try but unsuccessfully

#!/bin/bash
for i in {A..Z} ; do
    d=$RANDOM
    mkdir $d
    for j in {1..9} ; do
        e=$RANDOM
        echo Making $d/$e
        touch $d/$e
    done
done

It just created multiple dirs with random names and random files in them. Where I do go wrong?

Comment: If you don't want random names, why are you using $RANDOM?? You have the values you want in $i and $j. You can find solutions on the internet, but you have to think about them and try to understand them.

Comment: Quick update, sucessfully made the directories from A to Z.
Used the  following command:
for char in {A..Z}; do
Now looking forward to make files from 1 to 9 in each of them.

Comment: Also posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731401/script-that-make-folders-from-a-z-and-files-in-every-folder-from-0-9

Comment: you don't need loops for it. `mkdir` and `touch` works fine with multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, fr3dch3n from Stack Overflow gave the answer. Here it is.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
count=0

for x in {A..Z}; do
    mkdir ${x}
    pushd ${x} > /dev/null
    for y in {0..9}; do
        count=$((count + 1))
        touch $y
    done
    popd > /dev/null
done

mkdir counter
echo $count > counter/result
```

Comment: If you found the answer on Stack Overflow, the correct thing to do would be to link back to that answer. Also, I removed your follow-up question, because the Stack Exchange format is one question per Question and one answer per Answer. If you have follow-up questions, [they're free!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58732948/4957508)

Comment: Thank you alot for making me notice that. Sorry for missundarstanding, still learning how to use the system.